# Limit of logarithm function

Tags: limits

I am trying to find $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\ln(a+x)-\ln(a-x))$. But I am having a little difficulty to get the solution.

What I did so far was rewrite the expression as $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln((a+x)/(a-x))$ and as x goes to infinity I get $\infty/\infty$. If I use L'Hospital I get $\ln(-1)$ which is impossible. So can anyone help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: $\ln(a - x)$ isn't defined (at least as a real function) whenever $x \ge a$.

Comment: how about  In((a+ix)/(a-ix))?

Comment: @leo, if you're goint into the complex logarithm please do specify what *exactly* are $\;a,x\;$ and what branch do you choose.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Actually i was trying to solve the limit of the integral of 1/z, z is complex such that boundaries of the integrals are a+ix and a-ix and as x goes to infinity. since the function is analytic when Re(z)>0 x is any value which is greater or equal to Re(z)>0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $a$ and $x$ are real, you the consider the limit, when $x$ goes to infinity, of $$\log \left(\frac{(a+i x)^2}{a^2+x^2}\right)$$ which is, almost as you noticed,$\log \left(i^2\right)=2 \log (i)$. And $\log (i)=\frac{i \pi }{2}$. So, the limit is $i \pi$.

Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm